# Default Parameters: <T = SomeType> vs <T extends SomeType = SomeType>?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

TS seems to interpret the Default Parameter signature `T = SomeType` as `T extends any = SomeType`.  The compiler cannot (chooses not to?) implicitly type `T` to `SomeType`, as it would for a literal `let s = "string, not any!"`.  Why not?

Here's a sample scenario to illustrate.  The code works as is with `<T extends SomeType = SomeType>` (Extends+Default), but fails with `<T = SomeType>` (Default Parameter).  What work is the extra `extends SomeType` doing?

##### Sample Scenario

`Store` subclasses are registered in a `Registry` class as a dictionary (`type Stores = Record<string, Store>`) by store name. `Registry.getStore` should only accept registered store names as its `name` argument.  ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgyhA9lApggN4BQCCADlAJYBuwEhBA5tZFAJ4BcCASvq3YcA3CTKUAriGTVYCYABMFAFRz9B0DgAoWbTT3V7OASmLjyEABZsAdLqEIAvAnubR5AL4kvJFGgwAqmD4UNh4hPgAHowAdgoYYQTEXn7oCAAyeokR0fhxCbhJRD4QHBSE2RjO-LB4CgA87NQxzAA0WIX4AHxiAPS9qRiGQvXKTh3hYF1m-YN8AkYcowhRsfETBFNmc8Oay6t565XjldOk5JCTPMqi4rUx7BLweFqXm9em5+QIAPIgAFb4eA2ejICT4MCvTpgYw2ABmeAAonBLFooeFTI4zuZvm98DZFCo1AshForGxjO5vh5KTjyWAbHiqggmVSfOR+ggAOQxYAAW3wXJZlhwEmQCgQOBiyA48lgsHwFEQrhC+AleIQvIFYHEFCkMjkzHwEGyWi1+B4AGt8BwcHCEMpjDxsmZvi5jRIoDEEPTGdCANrmgC6bO8fV6CAUEj5fNljEgCGakGAMQVOvuCYkwSgzJi+AA7gggiFTbSM4gZAnnHnC5lIKXROX3RpOOMa-MW9oiAgsyEwO1K4gabdObU+RRqMgQsLReK5fKlb4pQnmDgcAoXc5XJwbEaTZ0tFzezmubTRzhx5Pp2ARWKJQRAfAlw9ECBFJvm4td8bTTycBAAFpgAAlUCAUAC8VPUQgA))

```js
abstract class Store {
  private registry: Registry;

  public addToRegistry(registry: Registry) {
    this.registry = registry;
  }
}

class UserStore extends Store {}
class ListStore extends Store {}

type Stores = Record<string, Store>

//class Registry<T = Stores> {
//class Registry<T extends Stores> {
class Registry<T extends Stores = Stores> {
  stores: T;

  constructor(stores: T) {
    Object.values(stores).forEach((store) => {
      store.addToRegistry(this);
    });
    this.stores = stores;
  }

  // 'name' should only accept registered store names
  public getStore(name: keyof T): Store {
    return this.stores[name];
  }
}

// dummy test instances
const users = new UserStore();
const list = new ListStore();
const registry = new Registry({ users, list });

// compiler should acccpt
const goodStore = registry.getStore('users');
// compiler should reject
const badStore = registry.getStore('not-a-registered-store');
```

✅ `class Registry<T extends Stores = Stores>` [Extends+Default]

`class Registry<T = Stores>` [Default Parameter]

- ❌ `store` in the constructor is of type `any`
- ❌ `getStore` has compiler error `T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'Store'`.
- I tried this first, expecting it to work. Hey TS, by default `T` *equals* a Store dictionary!
- Seems less redundant than `T extends Stores = Stores`

What am I missing?

Comment: `T extends Stores` is needed in your case, because if you would use just `T  = Stores`, one could as well initialize the Registry with: `Registry<number>`. This gets prevented since `T extends Stores` equals `T extends Record<string, any>` which in turn forces T to be an object rather than a primitive type or something different.

Answer (score 0):

Given a generic class, receiving a generic type `T`. This means, you can pass on any given type, e.g. number, string, object, Foo etc.

```js
class Registry<T> { /* ... */ }
```

The subset of eligible operations are then restricted. Based on your example, the getter `getStore` is not available on just `T`.

Forcing the `Registry` to only accept types of `Stores` one must use the `extends` keyword. This tells the compiler, to expect only types which conforms the given type (referred as Generic Constraints). For example: `T extends string`, the following would be conform: `Registry<"someString">`, `Registry<string>` and so on.

So, `T extends Stores` requires now, a store. You can pass on this store as a default type which results in: `T extends Stores = Store` alternatively you could provide this generic when instantiating the Registry.

This means, the following is your solution:

```js
class Registry<T extends Stores = Stores>
```

P.S: You can as well leave out the default `= Stores`, as it's not needed. TypeScript can infer this.

```js
class Registry<T extends Stores> { /* ... */ }
// ...
const registry = new Registry({ users, list });
const goodStore = registry.getStore('users');
```

To answer your question about `let s = "some string"`. Yes exactly, TypeScript does type this as `string`. But, keep in mind it's a variable, once the type of `s` is set, you cannot assign a number to it like:

```js
let s = "some string";
s = 5; // ❌ causes type error: number is not assignable to string
```

Whereas a generic can be anything expect, unless you construct it the way you want it to be `extends` keyword.

You can read about [Generic Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) in the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately not in this scenario: _"P.S. You can as well leave out the default = Stores, as it's not needed. TypeScript can infer this."_   TS cannot infer Store when we reference `Registry` in `Store`: `Generic type 'Registry<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).` Check out the playground. The simple `extends` variant is currently commented out.  It's `class Registry<T extends Stores = Stores>` or nothing!

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your response.  Yes, I understand exactly how TS behaves:  implicit type conversion for variables but not for generic defaults.  If there is no deeper reason for this than _"it is what it is, live with it"_, then that's OK with me!

Comment: I have no deeper reason for you at hand, other than, this is only possible with Generic Constraints. Because T could become technically anything. Yes, indeed, I missed you're linking back the registry to the store. So any store has a hard dependency on a Registry and since there is no default Type available anymore, this must be declared whenever Registry is used. This could be a solution: https://tsplay.dev/mpvABw